# Will my troops being researched in the laboratory keep going if I upgrade my laboratory?

Tags: clash-of-clans

Will my troops being researched in the laboratory keep going if I upgrade my laboratory? Or will they stop?

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! I don't play Clash of Clans, so I can't answer you actual question, but here's some free advice: it's best to use your question as the title. When your question is linked on the sidebar, people will just see the title. Maybe something like "Do my laboratories continue research after being upgraded?"

Answer (score 1):

It [continues](http://forum.supercell.net/showthread.php/523127-If-i-upgrade-lab-while-research-still-going-on-will-it-pause-or-continue). Like an Army Camp or Storage, it doesn't stop functioning.

However, you cannot research anything new while it's upgrading.